# Swiper slider inside google maps infowindow?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, swiper.js

I'm trying to display a swiper slider inside the google Maps info window. I am getting images as an array and the slider will be dynamic. With my current approach swiper is not initializing properly. I have already installed the swiper slider package for Angular from their official website.

This is what I have done -

```
private pilloMap!: google.maps.Map;

initMap(){
    const mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    }
    this.pilloMap = new google.maps.Map(mapEl, mapOptions);
    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for (const location of this.locations) {
        const marker = createHTMLMapMarker({
            latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng),
            map: this.pilloMap,
            label: location.price
        })

        /**
        * *Showing info window on click marker
        */
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (event: Event) => {
            const arr = ['...imagepath', '...imagepath'];
            const html = Array.from({ length: arr.length })
                    .map(
                        (_, i) => `
                        <ng-template swiperSlide>
                            <img src="${arr[i]}" alt="">
                        </ng-template>
                    `
                    )
                    .join('');
            const infoWindow = `
                <swiper #swiper>
                    ${html}
                </swiper>
            `;

            infowindow.setContent(infoWindow);
            infowindow.setOptions({
                zIndex: 90,
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 85)
            );
            infowindow.open({
                anchor: marker,
                map: this.pilloMap,
                shouldFocus: true
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Same problem here. Are you already find a solution?